# Term for accumulated hacks making code maintenance too expensive

Tags: terminology

I'm looking for the term used to describe when the amount of cumulated hacks and workarounds have made a software code too expensive to maintain at a reasonable level of quality.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better asked on Code Review

Comment: I disagree, code quality is an extremely important part of software quality assurance in the software development life cycle. Personally as a QA engineer I am teaching CleanCode practises to developer if they have no knowledge of this. This is a very valid question, that does not fit codereview. It might be better and be already asked on http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider Ward Cunningham's *[technical debt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt)* metaphor. It isn't exactly what you describe. Technical debt is more the *accumulation* of hacks and workarounds, even if the accumulated expense is not yet "too expensive to maintain."

But it seems like it's in the ballpark of what you're asking about.

Comment: This is the term I was looking for, read it in a tech magazine a few months ago. Seems that I didn't remember the exact definition either and that was my problem while googling.

Comment: I always thought tech-debt as a term was used when you knowingly add technical hacks to your product. Not when it was collected naturally overtime, but as I am writing this I think you might be spot-on as not knowing is worse and leads to more debt probably.

Comment: The question said 'too expensive', not 'more expensive' so I feel that my answer is more correct.  Just sayin'

Answer (score 1):

[Robert C. Martin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Cecil_Martin) also known as UncleBob has coined a term for this "**Clean Code**" the other way around is what you are describing and unmaintainable, un-extendable messy piece of code that smells. This would be unclean-code or messy-code, but also known as [QuickAndDirtyCodeTM](http://www.joelhelbling.com/articles/2010/12/10/whats-so-wrong-with-quick-and-dirty-code).

UncleBob wrote a book ([Clean Code](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132350882)) about it that is a must read for any developer if you ask me. Be sure to watch [his video](https://cleancoders.com/episode/clean-code-episode-1/show) explaining what types of unclean code you have and how it can ruin companies. He is a bit excentric, but if you can view past that it is a great watch.

This leads to "[code smells](https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/smells)", these are recongizable piece of code that match one or more known code smells. Martin Fowler wrote a book ([Refactoring](https://martinfowler.com/books/refactoring.html)) about how to change smelly code in to better clean code.

Answer (score 1):

Hacks and workaround are technical debt.

A term I have heard commonly used for too much of them is

### Drowning in technical Debt